# Can I reassign a SASS variable based on viewport width (media queries)

Tags: html, css, sass

Using SASS, I'd like to use different variables depending on viewport width. This is what I currently do:

```
$color: red;

div {
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    $color: red;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    $color: orange;
  }
}

p {
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    $color: red;
  }
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    $color: orange;
  }
} 

/*hundreds of other selectors similarly written*/
```

Is there a quicker/better way of doing this? For instance, something like this pseudo-code?:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  $color: red;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  $color: orange;
}

div { 
  background-color: $color;
}

p {
  background-color: $color;
}

/*hundreds of other selectors similarly written*/
```

---

EDIT:

Just discovered [this solution](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/sass-scss-how-can-i-make-a-variable-change-values-with-different-media-queries) (1st answer). Will go for it if people can confirm it's a common/recommended one...The same solution pops up [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/340).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redeclare any variable anywhere you want in their current scope. The value of the variable will then be used until it is redeclared again.

---

```
$foo: red;

body {
  background-color: $foo;
  
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    $foo: blue;
    
    background-color: $foo;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    $foo: green;
    
    background-color: $foo;
  }
}
```

---

```
:root {
  --color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  :root {
    --color: blue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  :root {
    --color: green;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if its possible to avoid having to type `@media...` in each selector - kind of like the 'pseudo-code' example I give in my question

Comment: @tonitone120, Yup, but this is not achievable with a native SCSS function, you just need pure CSS, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

yes, mixin will do the work for you

```
@mixin styling($main-color) {
    // your SCSS here, e.g.
    div {
        background-color: $main-color;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   @include styling($main-color: red);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
   @include styling($main-color: orange);
}
```

Comment: That would mean having to nest all my already existing selectors inside mixins which get further nested inside media queries. Seems awkward and I don't think it'd keep things 'DRY'. Have you seen this approach commonly used?

Comment: I just know this one only